# I want a 4k monitor slicer into 4 1080p monitors

Tags: hdmi, multiple-monitors, splitters

I searched everywhere and the closest I found was QuadHead2Go which is an overkill and too expensive... this is a sketch I made:

[Question I made with a sketch on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/VIDEOENGINEERING/comments/qngqu9/i_tried_explaining_this_in_another_post_but_i/)

So if anyone has any idea of a cheap product that does that, I appreciate it... or even so the name of what it is... I thought slicer would be a godd fit but couldn´t find anything with that query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I purchased this:

https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=21970

which was exactly what I needed, and it worked great on windows and linux